# Impossible to set A2DP profile on bluetooth headset

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I know this was asked a lot of times, but honestly I've tried everything that I could find over the internet and still couldn't resolve this.

I am a beginner user of Ubuntu 20.04 and I am having issues setting A2DP profile for a pair of bluetooth headset, and the quality is very bad.

- I have paired, trusted and connected the headphones via terminal `bluetoothctl` then `pair`, `trust`, `connect`, didn't work
- also installed `Blueman` and did the same process there again with no luck

After this I've tried to:

- set the profile A2DP firstly from OS GUI that didn't work
- then I've tried from `Blueman` but no success here either -> `(Failed to change profile to a2dp_sink)`
- installed `pavucontrol` and tried again from there - in `pavucontrol` I go to Config tab and in headphone's profile dropdown I can see `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)(unavailable)` so of course, I cannot set it here also

I have also checked `pacmd list-cards`, checked the `index` of headphones, then `pacmd set-card-profile <index> a2dp_sink` but I get `Failed to set card profile to 'a2dp_sink'.`. I've also tried to `sudo pacmd set-card-profile <index> a2dp_sink` and now I get `No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.` PulseAudio is installed, I've checked with `pulseaudio --version` `pulseaudio 13.99.1`.

I've edited the `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` file and added this line in the end of it: `Disable=Headset`, this didn't work. I've also tried to add same line in `main.conf` - no success.

With `bluez` installed, I've also enabled this line `Name = BlueZ` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`, again nothing.

In `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` I've also uncommented `#MultiProfile = off` and changed it to `MultiProfile = multiple`, nothing happened.

So after mixing all the steps above and restarted bluetooth and re paired headphone a million times, I gave up and I'm writing for help.

Please give any hint on what could be the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/642381/impossible-to-set-a2dp-profile-on-bluetooth-headset-on-ubuntu-20-04